# How to get the N latest data and display that in the angularjs nvd3 stacked area chart

Tags: stacked-area-chart, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I'm using angularjs-nvd3-directives to create stacked area chart.
Now my problem is I'm polling hundreds of data from server and I need to display on the the N latest data. How will I do that?

Here's the HTML file

```
<div ng-controller="GraphController as viewAll">    
<nvd3-stacked-area-chart    data="viewAll.data"     
id="graph"  showXAxis="true"    showYAxis="true"    
showLegend="true"   interactive="true"  
tooltips="true"     forcex="[xFunction()]">         
<svg></svg>     </nvd3-stacked-area-chart> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a second array that holds only the last N values and pass that as the 'data' parameter instead of the full data array.

```
  $scope.viewAll.visData = $scope.viewAll.data.slice(Math.max($scope.viewAll.data.length - N, 1))
```

In your html:

```
<nvd3-stacked-area-chart 
  data="viewAll.visData" 
  ...
>
```